# Flashforge Adventurer 3 - bed temperature not going over 89 °C

Tags: heated-bed, thermistor, flashforge-adventurer-3

I have an issue with my Flashforge Adventurer 3. When printing with ABS, the bed temperature is not going over 89 °C. Additionally, when I connect to the printer with Flashprint, it displays a negative bed temperature (when I connect to the printer, the bed temperature is displayed as -11 °C).

Is it somehow possible to calibrate the temperature? Or is there any other solution for this issue?

Comment: Welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Note that many beds will not reach the 100 °C mark. Insulation sometimes makes a difference. What is more concerning is the negative bed temperature, this usually tells you the thermistor is bad. Have you recently changed the firmware for a custom firmware?

Comment: it could also be a mis-calibrated thermosensor

Comment: @0scar I already did two firmware updates, but I didn't install a custom firmware, it was always the original Flashforge firmware that got updated.

Comment: @Trish Do you know whether it's possible to calibrate the thermosensor?

Comment: It is good to know that you used original firmware upgrades, this rules out an incorrect thermistor translation table (voltage to temperature). With respect to the mis-calibration, using an estimated room temperature of about 20 °C (depends on your room temperature/location) you get a 31 °C offset, so a 120 °C bed temperature which is usually higher than the beds can go. If insulated well, the best you can get from beds is about 110 °C as far as I know.

Comment: Calibrating a Thermosensor is altering the associated table in the firmware. Which is why it is essential to know if you altered the firmware.

Comment: @0scar 110 witnout a chamber and normal setup. My local materials science lab in the uni had a setup that for (as fasr as the student claimed) could get 130 bed temperature, but he didn't tell what was the setup... :/

Comment: I can only estimate the room temperature, I would guess about 17°C. 

Maybe I should try to install the firmware version that has been installed when I bought It (if that is possible). After the purchase it was working well, but I can't remember when the behavior changed.